# increment/decrement $_SESSION variable when button is click. Hint header()

Tags: php, session

I Initialized a `$_SESSION variable = 1` and I want to `increment/decrements` its value when a link is click. And the links will reload the page then echo the value of the `$_SESSION`. I was given a hint redired using `header()` but I still can't figure it how.

```
<?php  
        if (isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
        } else {
            $count = '';
        }
    ?>
    <a href="index.php?inc=TRUE">Increment</a>
    <a href="index.php?dec=TRUE">Decrement</a>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['count'])): ?>
        <?php echo $count ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: You should try using ajax for increment/decrement variables

Comment: but can it work without using ajax and only plain php? I was given a hint (Hint: redirect using header("Location: nameofscript.php"); after increasing or decreasing the session variable.). Please help I am new to PHP

Comment: <?php session_start() ?>
<?php  
 $count = 1;

 if (isset($_GET['inc'])==TRUE) {
  $counter++;
  $_SESSION['count'] = $count;
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
 if (isset($_GET['dec'])==TRUE) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = $count;
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
?>

Comment: @Tahir not necessary, depending on what you try to achive

Comment: yes you can do it without ajax but it will a little more complex, also it will take more execution time

Comment: please guide me how. ^_^

Comment: ok your code is working correctly only issue is that the variable $count resets to 1 every time you make a request to that code snippet, so therefore you don't see any changes in that variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0;

    $counter = $_SESSION['count']; 
    $counter = (int)$counter;

    if (isset($_GET['inc'])==TRUE) { 
        $counter++;
        $_SESSION['count'] = $counter; 
        header("Location: index.php"); 
    }

    if (isset($_GET['dec'])==TRUE) { 
        $counter--;
        $_SESSION['count'] = $counter; 
        header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
?>
```

Also You may need to cast $counter to int..

Comment: sir is possible to not increment or decrement if you reload the page? only inc/dec when a link is click?

Comment: yes it is possible but then you may need so javascript as well

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location: index.php")` is a php redirect. In this case if the code above is in the **index.php** file already, there's no need to redirect the user.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['count']) { // first time opening the page
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0; // initializing the counter
    } else { // counter already have a value
        if(isset($_GET['inc'])) { // increasing
            echo ++$_SESSION['count']; // no need for extra variable (preincrement to echo immediately)
        }
        if(isset($_GET['dec'])) { // decreasing
            echo --$_SESSION['count']; // no need for extra variable (predecrement to echo immediately)
        }
    } 
?>
<a href="index.php?inc=TRUE">Increment</a>
<a href="index.php?dec=TRUE">Decrement</a>
```